# How do I change my label value to the random number?

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

The random number value should be printing to my label named 'number' - Visual C#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
        number.Text = randomNumber();  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the value, Don't use it like a function

```
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
number.Text = randomNumber.ToString() ;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Random random = new Random();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{

    int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);
    number.Text = randomNumber();  
}
```

Comment: I was going to upvote for putting the Random initializer outside the method so multiple call in short time won't generate identical number, but randomNumber isn't a method